# Почему SERVER_ADDR имеет не тот IP

Tags: php, linux, centos, apache2

Установлен VirtualBox под Win 8. На нем стоит CentOS7 с apatche, php, mysql. Пробросил порт 80-й через virtualbox
(Адрес хоста - 192.168.100.4, Адрес гостя - 10.0.2.15 (это ip CentOS)).
Заходу по адресу http://192.168.100.4/info.php и открываю PHPinfo. И вижу вот такое.

```
SERVER_NAME 192.168.100.4
SERVER_ADDR 10.0.2.15
SERVER_PORT 80
REMOTE_ADDR 10.0.2.2
```

Почему SERVER_ADDR имеет такой IP а не 192.168.100.4

Аналогично

```
_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]  192.168.100.4
_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]  10.0.2.15
_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]  80
_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]  10.0.2.2
```

У меня из-за этого не ставится Wordpress. Т.е. я захожу в установку wordpress по адрес http://192.168.100.4/ и в коде страницы вижу УРЛы с ip 10.0.2.15. А они соответственно не открываются.

[Вот видео с проблемой](https://youtu.be/P7XkQ6pITTM)

Comment: Если в 8-й винде есть файл hosts, то попробуйте там прописать имя хоста.

Comment: А откуда гостю знать, какой у хоста ip-адрес? Хост выдал гостю адрес 10.0.2.15 - вот он его и юзает, всё просто. А в вордпрессе адрес сайта где-то должен настраиваться

Comment: Адрес сайта ещё не ставился, т.к. установки ещё Wordpress не было.

Comment: Проблема курицы и яйца, однако. Но сомневаюсь, что в вордпрессе такой случай не предусмотрели, может спецы придут расскажут

Comment: SERVER_ADDR выставляется web-сервером на основе того ip, который у него на интерфейсе на который пришло подключение. А на сетевухе на виртуалке же у вас 10.0.2.15 ...

Comment: Тогда не пойму, почему такая проблема (прикрепил видео с описанием выше)

Comment: Почему бы просто не использовать бридж вместо NAT'а? :)

Comment: Почему так ? потому что так криво написан wordpress. поройтесь в его документации. может его разработчики сделали какой то способ обойти грабли, которые они сами же и положили

Comment: @Mike, это вообще не понятно, зачем встраивают установщики в CMS. Все равно же юзер воспользуется конструктором, а кодер сперва сделает все на локалхосте, а потом выгрузит.

Comment: Я думаю, что с wordpress все отлично. Это очень популярная CMS и думаю такой косяк там исключен. Все в настройках виртуалки. Но где - не знаю(

Answer (score -2):

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']  = "192.168.100.4";
```

Укажите первой строчкой, если проблема только в этом.
Также у них есть константа WP_SITEURL, можно ее установить в конфигурации. Вообще, у них в исходниках, кажется, SERVER_ADDR нигде не используется.